# Returning p values for each subject using lmList function

Tags: r, linear-regression, p-value

I am using the lmList function from the nlme package to return the coefficients of a linear model for each subject:

```
predictor_1 <- runif(100, 0, 1)
predictor_2 <- runif(100, 0, 1)
DV <- runif(100, 0, 1)
subjects <- rep(letters[1:5], 20)
items <- rep(1:10, 10)
data <- data.frame(DV, subjects, items, predictor_1, predictor_2)

model <- lmList(DV ~ predictor_1 + predictor_2 | subjects, data)
model_summary <- summary(model)

model_coef <- coef(model)
f <- model_summary$fstatistic[ , 1]
r2 <- model_summary$r.squared
output <- data.frame(model_coef, f, r2)
names(output) <- c("Intercept", "Predictor 1", "Predictor 2", "F Ratio", "R Squared")
output
```

I am now trying to get the p values for the entire linear model for each subject. The problem is, using unclass(model) or unclass(model_summary) only displays the p values for each subject's intercept and predictors separately, but not evaluated as the whole model, which is what I want.

Any advice at all would be very helpful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In the same way that an F ratio and R squared are provided for each subject, I want a p value for each subject. I don't mean I want one single p-value, but rather one p-value for each subject. Thank you for the quick response! Hopefully what I am looking to do makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the p-values associated with the f statistic

```
pvals <- lapply(model, function(mod) {
       stat <- summary(mod)$fstatistic
       pf(stat[1], stat[2], stat[3], lower=F)
   })
```

These will the p-values you see if you do `summary(model[[1]])`